# Facing issue with SVG in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I am facing an issue, where I have used SVG in HTML page, but it isn't visible. Background has a gradient

```
<div id="logo">
    <svg class="icon icon-outline"><use href="#icon-name" fill="#ffffff" xlink:href="ic_fingerprint_48px.svg"/></svg>
    <h1>webSecure</h1>

</div>
```

```
.icon {
            fill: white;
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
        }
```

Any ideas, where I am wrong?

Comment: Do you not have to set a width and height in your svg tag to define it???

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Are you sure your path to the svg is correct? is the svg file in the same folder as this file?

Comment: try to set ID to your svg 'icon-name'

Comment: Just corrected path but still nothing :/

Answer (score 3):

If you're just going to be using an SVG file, then there's no need to use an `svg` tag. You can simply use a normal `img` tag:

```css
#logo img {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
    <img src="ic_fingerprint_48px.svg"/>
    <h1>webSecure</h1>
</div>
```

If you want to use inline SVG code so that you can change the `fill` color with CSS, then you need to extract the code from the `svg` file:

```css
.icon {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}
  .icon path {
    fill: red;
  }
```

```html
<div id="logo">  
  <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48"><path d="M35.62 8.94c-.16 0-.31-.04-.46-.11C31.33 6.85 28 6 24.02 6c-3.97 0-7.71.95-11.14 2.82a1.004 1.004 0 01-.96-1.76C15.65 5.03 19.72 4 24.02 4c4.26 0 7.98.94 12.06 3.05.49.25.68.86.43 1.35-.18.34-.53.54-.89.54zM7 19.44c-.2 0-.4-.06-.58-.18a.996.996 0 01-.24-1.39c1.98-2.8 4.51-5 7.51-6.55 6.29-3.25 14.33-3.26 20.63-.02 2.99 1.54 5.51 3.72 7.5 6.5.32.45.22 1.07-.23 1.39-.45.32-1.08.22-1.4-.23-1.8-2.52-4.08-4.5-6.78-5.88-5.74-2.95-13.07-2.94-18.8.02-2.71 1.4-5 3.39-6.79 5.93-.2.27-.51.41-.82.41zm12.51 24.13c-.26 0-.51-.1-.71-.3-1.73-1.75-2.67-2.86-4.02-5.27-1.38-2.46-2.11-5.47-2.11-8.69 0-5.94 5.08-10.78 11.33-10.78s11.33 4.83 11.33 10.78c0 .55-.45 1-1 1s-1-.45-1-1c0-4.84-4.18-8.78-9.33-8.78-5.14 0-9.33 3.94-9.33 8.78 0 2.88.64 5.54 1.85 7.71 1.29 2.3 2.15 3.29 3.69 4.84.39.39.39 1.03-.01 1.41-.18.21-.44.3-.69.3zm14.33-3.7c-2.38 0-4.47-.6-6.2-1.77-2.97-2.02-4.75-5.3-4.75-8.78 0-.55.45-1 1-1s1 .45 1 1c0 2.81 1.45 5.47 3.88 7.12 1.41.96 3.07 1.43 5.07 1.43.48 0 1.29-.05 2.09-.19.54-.1 1.06.27 1.16.81.1.54-.27 1.06-.81 1.16-1.17.21-2.16.22-2.44.22zM29.81 44c-.09 0-.18-.01-.26-.04-3.19-.87-5.27-2.05-7.43-4.2a14.642 14.642 0 01-4.33-10.44c0-3.25 2.76-5.89 6.16-5.89 3.4 0 6.16 2.64 6.16 5.89 0 2.14 1.87 3.89 4.16 3.89s4.16-1.74 4.16-3.89c0-7.54-6.5-13.67-14.49-13.67-5.69 0-10.88 3.16-13.22 8.06-.78 1.62-1.17 3.51-1.17 5.61 0 1.56.14 4.02 1.33 7.21.19.52-.07 1.09-.59 1.29-.52.19-1.09-.07-1.29-.59-.98-2.63-1.46-5.21-1.46-7.91 0-2.4.46-4.58 1.37-6.47 2.67-5.58 8.57-9.19 15.02-9.19 9.09 0 16.49 7.03 16.49 15.67 0 3.25-2.77 5.89-6.16 5.89s-6.16-2.64-6.16-5.89c0-2.14-1.87-3.89-4.16-3.89s-4.16 1.74-4.16 3.89c0 3.41 1.33 6.62 3.74 9.02 1.89 1.88 3.73 2.92 6.55 3.69.53.15.85.7.7 1.23-.12.44-.52.73-.96.73z"/></svg>
  <h1>webSecure</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: okay this works but only when I add fill property to `.icon` instead of `.icon path`

Comment: @jackowsky it should work either way, with some SVGs you will have multiple `paths` that make up the SVG, so if you wanted to have multiple colors, instead of adding the `fill` to the `svg`, you can add classes to each individual `path` and use different `fill` colors for each class.